# Insert jQuery's UI into page using Google

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, google-api

Hey All, I currently use Google's API to include jQuery into my sites like this:

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script>google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");</script>
```

How would I accomplish the same for the jQuery UI javascript and css files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For consistency with the way you're doing it you want:

```
google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");
google.load("jqueryui", "1.7.2");
```

http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/index.html#jqueryUI

Answer (score 14):

For the jQuery UI:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

This is the latest version.

Answer (score 4):

Since you're using the Google API, you can include jQuery UI with the following code:

```
google.load("jqueryui", "1.5.3");
```

Check the documentation [here](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/index.html#jqueryUI).

You will need to host the CSS Themes on your server.

Hosting your own CSS files allows you to create fully customized themes, give a look to the [Theme Roller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/).